# C: Random Number Generation - What (If Anything) Is Wrong With This

Tags: c, random

For a simple simulation in C, I need to generate exponential random variables. I remember reading somewhere (but I can't find it now, and I don't remember why) that using the rand() function to generate random integers in a fixed range would generate non-uniformly distributed integers. Because of this, I'm wondering if this code might have a similar problem:

```
//generate u ~ U[0,1]
u = (   (double)rand() / ((double)(RAND_MAX));
//inverse of exponential CDF to get exponential random variable
expon = -log(1-u) * mean;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Since u is uniformly distributed between 0 and 1, so is 1-u. In other words, there's no reason to write -log(1-u). Just write -log(u).

Comment: Thank you. Don't know why I missed that little bit.

Comment: @Jacob: Right. But, for the purposes of teaching/learning the technique (i.e. normalize, integrate, invert), it's nice to exhibit the solution in the redundant form none-the-less.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with random numbers in a fixed range is that a lot of people do this for numbers between 100 and 200 for example:

```
100 + rand() % 100
```

That is not uniform. But by doing this it is (or is close enough to uniform at least):

```
u = 100 + 100 * ((double)rand() / ((double)(RAND_MAX));
```

Since that's what you're doing, you should be safe.

Comment: A very simple solution is to use `random()` instead of `rand()`.  From the man page: "The `random()` and `srandom()` functions have (almost) the same calling sequence
and initialization properties as the `rand(3)` and `srand(3)` functions. The
difference is that `rand(3)` produces a much less random sequence -- in fact,
the low dozen bits generated by rand go through a cyclic pattern. All of the
bits generated by `random()` are usable. For example, `random()&01` will produce
a random binary value."

Answer (score 2):

In theory, at least, rand() should give you a discrete uniform distribution from 0 to RAND_MAX... in practice, it has some undesirable properties, such as a small period, so whether it's useful depends on how you're using it.

Answer (score 2):

RAND_MAX is usually 32k, while the LCG rand() uses generates pseudorandom 32 bit numbers. Thus, the lack of uniformity, as well as low periodicity, will generally go unnoticed.

If you require high quality pseudorandom numbers, you could try George Marsaglia's CMWC4096 (Complementary Multiply With Carry). This is probably the best pseudorandom number generator around, with extreme periodicity and uniform distribution (you just have to pick good seeds for it). Plus, it's blazing fast (not as fast as a LCG, but approximately twice as fast as a Mersenne Twister.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. The problem you're thinking of arises when you're clamping the output from `rand()` into a range that's *smaller* than `RAND_MAX` (i.e. there are fewer possible outputs than inputs).

In your case, you're (normally) reversing that: you're taking a fairly small number of bits produced by the random number generator, and spreading them among what will usually be a larger number of bits in the mantissa of your double. That means there are normally some bit patterns in the double (and therefore, specific values of the double) that can never occur. For most people's uses that's not a problem though.

As far as the "normally" goes, it's always possible that you have a 64-bit random number generator, where a double typically has a 53-bit mantissa. In this case, you could have the same kind of problem as with clamping the range with integers.

Answer (score 0):

No, your algorithm will work; it's using the modulus function that does things imperfectly.
 The one problem is that because it's quantized, once in a while it will generate exactly RAND_MAX and you'll be asking for `log(1-1)`.  I'd recommend at least `(rand() + 0.5)/(RAND_MAX+1)`, if not a better source like `drand48()`.

There are much faster ways to compute the necessary numbers, e.g. the [Ziggurat algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziggurat_algorithm).